# Best practices angularjs ajax request and redirect

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a originCtrl template and controller. In this one i have a button to go to another template and controller. But on the destCtrl, i need information from an ajax request.
This is a part of my controller code:

```
.controller('OriginCtlr', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
    $scope.startTest = function () {
        $http.post(API_URL + 'creates/tests.json', {'id':$scope.dic.id, 'nbQuestion':$scope.nbquestion}).success(function (data) {
            $rootScope.words = angular.toJson(data.words);
            $location.path('/questions');
        });
    };
})
.controller('DestCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
    $rootScope.$watch('words', function(newValue, oldValue) {
         scope.word = scope.counter + 1;
    });
})
```

I want to know where i have to do my ajax request:

1) do ajax request in the originCtlr, data in rootScoope, and redirect after success

2) do ajax request in the originCtlr, data in rootScoope, and redirect

3) pass argument in $location.pathand do ajax request in the destCtlr

4) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share data between controllers you should be using a *service*.

```
.service('testsService', function ($http, $location) {
    this.words = {};

    this.createTests = function (id, question) {
        $http.post(API_URL + 'creates/tests/json', {id: id, nbQuestion: question})
            .success(function (data) {
                this.words = angular.toJson(data.words);
                $location.path('/questions');
            }.bind(this));
    }
})
```

Then you can inject `testsService` into your controllers and access `words` from the service instead of using `$rootScope`.